# File Access Denied Exeption

Tags: c#, file, uwp, access-denied

I wrote a simple c# code to Post an audio file in `HttpMultipartForm` format, and when I try to access to the file in my hard disk, it throws an exception that access to path is denied.

```
using(var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{

   using(var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"),"https://www.iotype.com/api/recognize/file"))
   {

      multipartContent.Add(new StringContent("MyToken"), "token");
      multipartContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\audio.mp3")), "audio", Path.GetFileName("AUDIO_FILE.mp3"));

      request.Content = multipartContent;

      var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
      txtStatus.Text = response.Content.ToString();

    }
 }
```

Comment: This is by design.  A UWP app runs in a sandbox that restricts what an app can do.  Users like that, they can feel good that an app they download from the store isn't going to snoop on their private files.  FileOpenPicker required to allow them to give permission, capability must be declared in the manifest, the root directory of the C: drive is off limits.

Comment: So could you change this code to work properly with FileOpenPicker?

Comment: did you try to launch your visual studio in admin mode  ?

Comment: i think that you can use a file picker to get your file , check this link   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile

Comment: Sayah Imad, yes I tried to launch visual studio in admin mode, and It did not affect.
and Filepicker is for another purpose and its not related to restriction.

Answer (score 0):

UWP applications are restricted in terms of the directories and files they can access. The easiest way to navigate the restrictions is to use the WinRT types in the Windows.Storage namespace, the two primary classes being StorageFolder and StorageFile, In Windows Runtime for Windows 8 and 8.1, you couldn’t use FileStream or the Directory/File classes at all. This made it harder to write portable class libraries, so this restriction has been relaxed in UWP for Windows 10, although the limits on what directories and files you can access still apply.
**So its not possible to use File Class in UWP app.**

Answer (score 0):

In **UWP Applications** there is a lot of restriction because it's applications are embed into windows, imposed for reasons of architecture but also of security **(Isolation of Application Domain )**, it does not prevent that it exists Several ways to manage information (Reading, Writing) using **Windows API** in a dedicated application location.

## **Different Storage For UWP Application :**

- **The local storage :**

  `It's a default file system for application and it's identified by LocalFolder Class .`
- **The roaming storage :**

  `Has the same fearture than The Local Storage adding to that synchronization Data with windows Devices , identified by RoamingSettings Class.`
- **The temporary storage :**

  `As his name indicates It’s used mainly for caching scenarios .`